# Laplace Transformation: Determine the current through the inductor versus time i(t)

Tags: inductor, parallel, passive-networks, series

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsy2XG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am trying to find the current through the inductor versus time i(t) using Laplace transform.

Converting everything into the s-domain:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOvu1B.png)</sup>

I then complete KVL on Loop 1 (left loop 'I1'):

$$5/s - Z1(I1) - Z2(I1 - I2) = 0$$
$$5/s = Z1(I1) + Z2(I1) - Z2(I2)$$

Solved for I2 =  $$\frac{Z1(I1)+Z1(I1)-(5/s)}{Z2}$$

---

KVL on Loop 2 (right loop 'I2'):

$$Z2(I2-I1)-Z3(I2) = 0$$
$$Z2(I2)-Z2(I1)-Z3(I2) = 0$$

Solved for I2:  $$\frac{Z2(I2)}{Z2-Z3}$$

---

I2 = I2 therefore: $$\frac{Z1(I1)+Z1(I1)-(5/s)}{Z2} = \frac{Z2(I1)}{Z2-Z3}$$

Solving for I1 = $$\frac{(5/s)(Z2-Z3)}{(Z2Z1-Z1Z3-Z3Z2)}$$

However, once I substitute values in it becomes a algebraic mess and I can't seem to get a consistent result. The resulting plot (once converted back into t domain) should resemble something like this simulation:

[image]

Can anyone guide me through this? Have spent better part of two days on this problem!
Thanks in advance

Comment: We typically refer to the current THROUGH an inductor VERSUS time.  Voltage appears across a component.

Answer (score 1):

First, there's no such thing as the current "across", it's the current *through*. Then, the second equation seems odd, I wonder why didn't you choose the simpler path:

$$\begin{align}
\dfrac5s&=I_1sL+\dfrac{I_1-I_2}{sC} \tag{1} \\
\dfrac{I_1-I_2}{sC}&=I_2R \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

Try solving for \$I_1\$ now, and see what you get. Can you take it from here? Minor spoiler, here's what I get after substitution:

[image: result]

For brevity, the result of the simulation with LTspice:

[image: SPICE confirms it]

---

> Solving for I1 I get (5RC^2)s+5C/((RLC^2))s^3+(CL)s^2+(RC)s)

You must have done something wrong, somewhere. Step by step, this is what I get, starting with (2):

$$\begin{align}
\dfrac{I_1-I_2}{sC}&=I_2R \\
\dfrac{I_1}{sC}&=I_2R+\dfrac{I_2}{sC} \\
I_1&=I_2\left(R+\dfrac{1}{sC}\right)sC \\
I_1&=I_2(sRC+1) \tag{3} \\
\text{from (2):} \\
\dfrac5s&=I_2(sRC+1)sL+\dfrac{I_2(sRC+1)}{sC}-\dfrac{I_2}{sC} \\
\dfrac5s&=I_2\left[s^2RLC+sL+\dfrac{sRC+1-1}{sC}\right] \\
\dfrac5s&=I_2(s^2RLC+sL+R) \Rightarrow \\
I_2&=\dfrac{5}{s(s^2RLC+sL+R)} \tag{4} \\
\text{substitute (4) in (3):} \\
I_1&=\dfrac{5sRC+5}{s^3RLC+s^2L+sR}=\dfrac5s\dfrac{sRC+1}{s^2RLC+sL+R} \tag{5}
\end{align}$$

You can now perform partial fraction expansion. I'll get lazy and use `partfrac()`, `ilt()`, and `subst()` (and some gross roundings) in wxMaxima to get:

$$h(t)=\dfrac{5}{119}-1.0508\exp(-23343t)\sinh(466.85t)-0.042017\exp(-23343t)\cosh(466.85t) \tag{7}$$

The plots are the same.

Comment: Thanks @a concerned citizen 

I just realised I messed up the original mesh analysis too (Z2(I2-I1)). 
Thanks for the addition of your simulation aswell. We've just started on micro-cap... still trying to get my head around setting up the source parameters.

Thanks again!

Comment: @thatstheguy9 I used `PWL(0 0 1n 5)`, which is a piece-wise source with two pairs of time-data points: at t=0 it's 0 V, and at 1 ns it's 5 V. You could also achieve this with `PULSE(0 5 0 1n)` (but not in LTspice, due to some recent changes you'll need to fill in at least 5 parameters, and here there are only 4).

Comment: @a concerned citizen How are you getting that plot?

Solving for I1 I get (5RC^2)s+5C/((RLC^2))s^3+(CL)s^2+(RC)s)  

Converting to partial fractions and back into t-domain my result is 0.047e^(-23.34t) cos(23338t+153.5)

Comment: @thatstheguy9 You got something mixed up, somewhere, I've updated the answer.

Comment: @a concerned citizen Thank you. I've gone back over it and managed to arrive at the same result!

Answer (score 0):

The impedance of LC at resonance is \$Zo=√(L/C)\$ = 238 ohms and R = 238/2.  These are useful for determining the exponential damped cosine response.

It appears the R value was chose to be slightly overdamped with a Q=0.5 or \$\zeta=\dfrac{1}{2Q}=1\$  with Zo=119*2  thus you expect a response closer to a simple RL response with \$\tau=L/R=117 ~\mu s\$ . ( Q=0.5  is also know as the *Bessel* response for order=2)

### other

Although I get a [critically damped value](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCCsB0Z-DEBYCmBaAHCAjB6AmAdgwE5tIKMA2bJQyfKCRyCSdbbAKADcQBmfMwxZBEWknBSkbKRDDRIXAOYChIfCLUR%20YSfK4B5EEiRYJUUzisGATibgatM5mCzj8SgMYmSVDW6%20-pruONAYiJHw%20OiEULDwSNiEJGScSAzgXAA2JmbWkvz8-hbysNhg2KnVNbUgaAp6CLiaYDSmJPxZAO55WEJYSH4B7ly9LiN9k2BjUyFBTqPjjvOm-Vozy8Ki6vObUxZr07NFJVZiBRpcMl0X-JlUztj%208gD6gq9gr2ZUkK9-jT%20aGwr3wn3erwAkgA7AAmAFcvAAXAD2tmuYFu6iOjywkGwjAgSHeYK%20Pz%20APKnlewNB33eXCAA) that is closer to 125 Ohms which draws \$V/R=I=40~ mA\$ but it is not ζ=0.707 rather it is Q=125/238=0.525 and  ζ=0.95. hmm...

[image]

( for future reference)

https://hasler.ece.gatech.edu/Courses/ECE6414/Unit1/Discrete_01.pdf
https://hasler.ece.gatech.edu/Courses/ECE6414/Unit1/Discrete_02.pdf
etc